# Is there a mercurial built-in or extension to delete all "non-mercurial" files from repos root directory?

Tags: mercurial, configuration-management

I'd like all files under the repo's root folder except .hg/, .hgignore, .hgtags, etc.  Is there a mercurial built-in or existing extension to do this?

I have implemented a non-hg script with hard-code "mercurial files", but I'd like a programmatic method of excluding the mercurial related files.

I'm trying to mirror a non-mercurial configuration management server (Starteam) by periodically deleting all files, doing a clean checkout from Starteam and then running hg addremove, then checkin.

Comment: I think it's good to assume that any hg related file will start with `.hg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly what you're looking for but `hg update -r null` takes your to the revision before the first changeset, which obviously contains no files.  That'll leave your .hg in place but .hgtags and .hgignore will be-gone.  However, they're tracked files so they'll come back with a `hg update` the same as any other files.

Comment: After updating to null I can't just checkout all the files from the non-mercurial cm server and checkin since this would create a new unrelated branch.  If there was a command to "update to a revision without updating the working directory", then this would work.

Maybe I need to reword the question?

Comment: That command does exist, it's 'hg debugsetparent', but I do really think what you want to do is 'hg update -r null' followed by 'hg update -r whateverrevisionyouwant'

Answer (score 0):

For each version you pull from Starteam, I'd suggest creating a new directory.

In this directory, do a [`hg clone -U`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-CommonProblems.I_want_a_clean.2C_empty_working_directory) from your previous directory.  This will clone the repository, but not checkout any files.  After which, copy your Starteam files and then do an `hg addremove`.

Comment: this will create a new branch for each revision, it's not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the whole Starteam stuff into a subfolder of your repo's root folder.

Like this:

```
/MyRepo/
/MyRepo/.hg
/MyRepo/.hgignore
/MyRepo/Starteam/
/MyRepo/Starteam/Starteam file 1
etc.
```

So you only have to delete this single "Starteam" folder, without the need to explicitly ignore Mercurial specific files.